# Display variable within TextBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Im having difficulty displaying a variable within a text box.

Mainly trying to understand the way that Bindings work in XAML.

I need to try to display the variable `TextBoxFileName` and `TextBoxFilePath` in the relevant fields. The information the variables are retrieving is stored within a seperate `GlobalVariableStorage` class. I do not want the `TextBox` fields to be editable so ive set them as read only. I do not want the user to be able to edit the data in these fields at all. If you have ideas for alternative display methods, please feel free to suggest.

**XAML**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <!-- Placeholder for the theme dictionary -->
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<Frame Background="{StaticResource CustomAcrylicDarkBackground}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Width="500" Header="File Name" PlaceholderText="Name Of File" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="White" Text=""/>
        <TextBox Width="500" Header="File Location" PlaceholderText="File Location" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="White" Text=""/>
    </StackPanel>
</Frame>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
public sealed partial class SettingsPage : Page
    {
    public SettingsPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class TextBoxDisplay
    {
        public string TextBoxFileName = GlobalVariables.FileName;
        public string TextBoxFilePath = GlobalVariables.FilePath;           

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two read-only properties to your `SettingsPage` class:

```
public sealed partial class SettingsPage : Page
{
    public SettingsPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string TextBoxFileName => GlobalVariables.FileName;
    public string TextBoxFilePath => GlobalVariables.FilePath;
}
```

...and bind to these:

```
<TextBox Header="File Name" ... Text="{x:Bind TextBoxFileName}"/>
<TextBox Header="File Name" ... Text="{x:Bind TextBoxFilePath}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are having a difficult time because you have a wrong approach.
For instance, you didn't follow the MVVM pattern. Plus, you don't need to set the `IsReadOnly` to true, you just use One-Way Binding.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxFileName,Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

To understand and implement MVVM correctly, I suggest you to read the following links: [MVVM for WPF](http://www.learnmvvm.com/). Although it is for WPF, but UWP is very similar to WPF, you won't get any problem.

If you want to learn MVVM, I can help you. Just send me a message on Discord: Red Wei#2396

Have fun.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I will certainly take you up on that offer.